# panTo without raising an event

Tags: knockout.js, leaflet

I'm trying to marry together leaflet with knockout and I have a minor problem with the bindings I've created. I have this at the moment:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.map = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var obj = valueAccessor();
        var coordsObj = allBindings.get("location");
        var coords = coordsObj ? ko.unwrap(coordsObj) : { lat: 41.5047729, lng: -81.6856701 };
        var map = L.map(element).setView(coords, 16);
        L.esri.basemapLayer("Streets").addTo(map);

        map.on("moveend", function (e) {
            var latlng = e.target.getCenter();
            coordsObj(latlng);
        });
        obj(map);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.location = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var map = ko.unwrap(allBindings.get("map"));
        var val = valueAccessor();
        var coords = ko.unwrap(val);
        map.panTo(coords, { animate: true });
    }
};
```

Which is bound like this:

```
<div id="map" data-bind="map: map, location: location"></div>
```

This seems to work, but if I update my `location` observable it will call the `update` function which will call `map.panTo` as required. However, `.panTo` will cause a `moveend` event to fire, which updates `location`, which causes the `update` function to fire again, which calls `panTo` again...(at this point, you don't get seem to get a `moveend`, presumably because it hasn't actually moved).

This isn't a huge deal, it doesn't seem to really slow it down, but it is annoying and inefficient so I'd like to be able to remove it on principle. So is there a good way to pan the map with causing `moveend` to fire? Or is there a good way to communicate from the `location` binding to the event handler in the `map` binding to say "ignore this `moveend`"?

Comment: I assume after the initial move that perhaps the coords aren't exact and they get rounded in some way in the call to `panTo` - the update wouldn't fire on location if it were given the exact same value again.  I'm not familiar with leaflet - is there some way to "normalise" the coords before you call `panTo` so they're ones that it wouldn't then change internally before firing `moveend`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: That's my assumption too. I'm sure after the move the *actual* coordinates and the coordinates I'd asked for are slightly off due to rounding (and also why after another update cycle it doesn't seem to fire again). I thought about checking if the coordinates at the end of the `moveend` are within some tolerance of the `location`, but that feels a bit hacky.

Comment: What if you use [this method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng) and do: `map.panTo(L.latLng(coords.lat, coords.lng), { animate: true });` - perhaps that would normalise them?

Answer (score 3):

> So is there a good way to pan the map with causing moveend?

No, not without extending `L.Map` and adding the needed functionality. Which could lead to troubles if the API changes so that's not really an option.

Why not remove the handler before calling `panTo` by using the `map.off('moveend', function () {});` method and afterwards reattaching the handler using the `map.on('moveend', function () {});` method?

Comment: Hmmm...that's a thought.

Comment: Yes this is a nice approach.  One thing that makes it "not so nice" at the moment is the fact your binding handlers are both separate objects - perhaps you could refactor so that you have a single handler along the lines of `data-bind="leaflet: {map: map, location: location}"` - that way you'd have better access (scoping wise, modularity etc) to remove and re-add the `moveend` handler within the one binding handler

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Ahh, that is a better idea. I think I initially didn't do that because I thought it would be able to see the changes in `location`, but of course, it's an observable in my view model and it's still an observable when I add it to the object literal passed to the binding!

Comment: @MattBurland I _think_ you could do it your way - with just the `map` handler.  The `location` handler doesn't have to exist at all, you could do `allBindings.get("location").subscribe(function(v) { /*where this is your current location update function*/ });` within your `map init`.  I'm pretty sure that knockout doesn't throw an error if a binding handler doesn't exist.  Could be wrong though...

Comment: Annoyingly, that seems like it ought to work and after calling `panTo` it hasn't fired a `moveend` event, but it seems as soon as I reattach the handler it decided it need to immediately fire a `moveend` event anyway. So when I manually change `location`, it seems that I'm still seeing a `moveend` event from somewhere.

Comment: So a different take on it then - `dontFireMoveEnd = true; panTo(...); dontFireMoveEnd = false;` and in the `moveEnd` handler `if (!dontFireMoveEnd) { ... }`.  Would still be easier to do such a thing if it were all contained in one handler though :)

Comment: could you test attaching the handler in a timeout? so that you're sure the map has stopped moving.